# how to specify the position of an img-tag by the center point

Tags: javascript, css

I have bigger sized image with multiple smaller imgage tags on top (map with points on it)

Right now I specify the position of a point with the top and left property inside the parent

```
 <div className='img-c' style={{ top: "12%", left: "60%" }}><img src={windowIcon} id="1x03" className="planF " /></div>
```

When resizing the window, the map will scale as well, the points on it not, so it is still clickable. However since they are fixed at the top left corner (I guess), it looks like they are moving on the map so I would like to know a way how to define the center point.

I am using Javascript React if that matters

Comment: If possible make a code snippet where we can see what's going on. For the top of my head, I'd suggest you use a div with a background image as the map, with position relative and make the smaller images (locations) position absolute. They should be in the correct location no matter the screen size.

Comment: _"so I would like to know a way how to define the center point"_ - not sure if that will actually help solve your problem, but if you want to position elements from the "center" of their relative positioned parent - then you can position them at `top: 50%; left: 50%` - and then use `transform:translate(..., ...)` to move them elsewhere from that center point.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'display: flex;', 'justify-content: center;' and 'align-items: center;' on image parent div.